# Convention for Expressions Involving Exponents

Tags: exponentiation, convention

Is there a reason why positive exponents are preferred in some settings over negative? Further, I've noticed if there's a positive rational exponent, then it is sometimes expressed as a product with factors: base to an integral power and the base to a fractional power less than one. E.g., $ x^2\sqrt{x} $ being preferred over $ xx^{3/2} $ or $ x^{5/2} $. Why would the first be preferred over the others?

Comment: This may have to do with what operations you have to perform later with the exponents.

Comment: I don't know what books you are reading, at what level, or on what topics in mathematics, but in college-level books on probability and statistics _only_ $x^{5/2}$ would be used as a final form.

Comment: I'm a tutor at a university and one of the older professors prefers $ x\sqrt{x} $ to $ x^{3/2} $ in final expressions for solutions. I agree working with the latter is easier, but we don't always put solutions in the easiest forms to work with. Did I do something wrong in asking this question?

Comment: I feel like this may have something to do with aesthetics; your professor probably believes improper fractions in the exponent don't look aesthetically pleasing when in a final answer.

Comment: That's an unexpected, but probably accurate answer. I didn't think to consider the aesthetics of the expression. I say it's unexpected because I figured this was much like how we still "rationalize the denominator," for in times past the rationalized denominator eased computation.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, $x^2x^{1/2}$ is *not* preferred over $x^{5/2}$, simply because the latter is much easier to deal with (e.g. integrate) and to write.

If I had to choose between $x^2x^{1/2}$ and $xx^{3/2}$ then I would definitely go for the former; writing $x^{5/2}$ like that at least has a purpose (i.e. to show that integer and fractional parts of the power).

Comment: I completely agree that this is usually the case. I have never written expressions like that until I was helping a student and heard that the professor wanted a solution in the form of $ x\sqrt{x} $ instead of $ x^{3/2} $. He expressly stated it to his class. Since I have never seen a setting where the former is preferred, I figured I'd ask here. It seems I've hit a nerve however.

Comment: Yes; usually we avoid fractional powers and write $x\sqrt x$ instead. This is slightly different from what you originally asked though...

Comment: So it is. I've made the edit.